# How to make a background-image scale to the height of a parallel div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two divs. On the left there will be a background image and on the right a div that contains text.

If I just have a single image in the div on the left I can create the setup I want with `display: flex;` whereby the background image div scales to be the height of div alongside ([see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zduo1est/)).

However I actually need a slideshow in the left div, meaning I must have multiple divs and images nested inside the outer div and therefore the background-image is no longer on the div that has the width set ([see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odcvq94w/1/)), meaning it doesn't scale as intended.

I can't figure out a way around this, can anyone provide any suggestions?

```css
.product-single__photos,
.bkgd-text {
  width: 50%;
}

.bkgd-img__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-image {
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-image:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkgd-img__container">
  <div class="product-single__photos ">
    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper js">
      <div class="product-single__photo" data-image-id="image-id">
        <div id="image-id" class="feature-row__image lazyload bkgd-image" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60');" tabindex="-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-single__info bkgd-text">
    <div class="product-single__meta">
      Product text goes here.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posse audire ne mel. Movet moderatius per te. Ut dictas appetere referrentur mel. Esse efficiantur at eum. Ius debitis habemus no, cum hinc feugait fierent in. Erant consectetuer at ius, id platonem inciderint
      efficiantur pro, utamur iudicabit cu cum. Eos ne labitur offendit omittantur, te vim diceret consequuntur signiferumque. Sea ut oratio exerci aeterno, per nibh ornatus in, vim falli animal delicatissimi cu. Facete eirmod vis no. His elitr ceteros
      scriptorem in, id impedit partiendo per, eu soluta legimus nominavi vis. Novum harum ne eam. Putant oportere consulatu sed ut, sit ut stet vidisse delectus. Te est veri minim reprehendunt, ea everti reformidans eum. Saepe malorum percipitur id nec,
      causae atomorum sit ei. Et has aperiri feugait inimicus. Ei solet nominavi interesset pro, novum aliquando duo at, qui postea principes scriptorem et. Id mei discere nominavi placerat, vel movet fuisset praesent et. Intellegat interesset vel in,
      nemore impetus ad usu, illud postea eu eam. At sit numquam iracundia. Nec ex tollit viderer perfecto, quidam fabulas qui ei, modo senserit suavitate ut nec. Mea ad prodesset efficiantur, sed te quidam molestiae, platonem pericula conceptam sed at.
      Ne mea dico assueverit, eu eius denique eos. Est scaevola percipitur accommodare ne, mei te dicam nusquam salutatus. Vis at iusto iudicabit. Sea cu voluptua invidunt tacimates, ea graecis denique oportere sed.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.product-single__photos` gets the flexbox height, and then you need to pass `height: 100%` to it's descendants:

```css
.product-single__photos,
.bkgd-text {
  width: 50%;
}

.bkgd-img__container {
  display: flex;
}

.product-single__photo-wrapper {
  height: 100%; /* <--- */
}

.product-single__photo {
  height: 100%; /* <--- */
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-image {
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; /* <--- */
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-image:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.bkgd-img__container .bkgd-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkgd-img__container">
  <div class="product-single__photos ">
    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper js">
      <div class="product-single__photo" data-image-id="image-id">
        <div id="image-id" class="feature-row__image lazyload bkgd-image" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60');" tabindex="-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-single__info bkgd-text">
    <div class="product-single__meta">
      Product text goes here.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, posse audire ne mel. Movet moderatius per te. Ut dictas appetere referrentur mel. Esse efficiantur at eum. Ius debitis habemus no, cum hinc feugait fierent in. Erant consectetuer at ius, id platonem inciderint
      efficiantur pro, utamur iudicabit cu cum. Eos ne labitur offendit omittantur, te vim diceret consequuntur signiferumque. Sea ut oratio exerci aeterno, per nibh ornatus in, vim falli animal delicatissimi cu. Facete eirmod vis no. His elitr ceteros
      scriptorem in, id impedit partiendo per, eu soluta legimus nominavi vis. Novum harum ne eam. Putant oportere consulatu sed ut, sit ut stet vidisse delectus. Te est veri minim reprehendunt, ea everti reformidans eum. Saepe malorum percipitur id nec,
      causae atomorum sit ei. Et has aperiri feugait inimicus. Ei solet nominavi interesset pro, novum aliquando duo at, qui postea principes scriptorem et. Id mei discere nominavi placerat, vel movet fuisset praesent et. Intellegat interesset vel in,
      nemore impetus ad usu, illud postea eu eam. At sit numquam iracundia. Nec ex tollit viderer perfecto, quidam fabulas qui ei, modo senserit suavitate ut nec. Mea ad prodesset efficiantur, sed te quidam molestiae, platonem pericula conceptam sed at.
      Ne mea dico assueverit, eu eius denique eos. Est scaevola percipitur accommodare ne, mei te dicam nusquam salutatus. Vis at iusto iudicabit. Sea cu voluptua invidunt tacimates, ea graecis denique oportere sed.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me. I've been stuck on this for ages!